# Confusion with paths while Xquerying

Tags: xml

can any one help me how to xquery this. The path is very confusing.I tried querying it but the result is null.I used all the possible paths to traverse through it but every time I'm arriving at a null output.

```
<package>
    <continent id="f0_119" name="Europe"/>
    <continent id="f0_123" name="Asia"/>
    <continent id="f0_126" name="America"/>
    <continent id="f0_129" name="Australia/Oceania"/>
    <continent id="f0_132" name="Africa"/>
    <country id="f0_492" name="India" capital="f0_1687" population="952107712" datacode="IN" total_area="3287590" population_growth="1.64" infant_mortality="71.1" gdp_total="1408700" inflation="9" indep_date="15 08 1947" government="federal republic" car_code="IND">
        <name>India</name>
        <city id="f0_8888" country="f0_492">
            <name>Pimpri Chinchwad</name>
            <population year="91">517083</population>
        </city>
        <province id="f0_18505" name="Andhra Pradesh" country="f0_492" capital="f0_8626" population="66508008" area="275045">
            <city id="f0_8626" country="f0_492" province="f0_18505" longitude="78.2" latitude="17.1">
                <name>Hyderabad</name>
                <population year="91">3145939</population>
            </city>
            <city id="f0_8791" country="f0_492" province="f0_18505">
                <name>Vishakhapatnam</name>
                <population year="91">752037</population>
            </city>
            <city id="f0_8801" country="f0_492" province="f0_18505">
                <name>Vijayawada</name>
                <population year="91">701827</population>
            </city>
            <city id="f0_8913" country="f0_492" province="f0_18505">
                <name>Guntur</name>
                <population year="91">471051</population>
            </city>
            <city id="f0_8928" country="f0_492" province="f0_18505">
                <name>Warangal</name>
                <population year="91">447653</population>
            </city>
            <city id="f0_9023" country="f0_492" province="f0_18505">
                <name>Rajahmundry</name>
                <population year="91">324881</population>
            </city>
        </province>
        <religions percentage="80">Hindu</religions>
        <religions percentage="2">Sikh</religions>
        <religions percentage="0.5">Jains</religions>
        <languages percentage="30">Hindi</languages>
    </country>
</package>
```

Comment: Show what you have tried and read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Also, tell us what information you want to extract. Here is a path that will give you non-null output: `*`. I don't know whether it will give you the information you want, because you haven't actually told us that.